# Posting a file to CodeIgniter backend

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to post a file to my CodeIgniter backend in the simplest way possible.

I want to fire an API call from Postman like this:

[image]

And my PHP function is looking like this right now:

```
public function runk_image_put()
{
    $image = $this->upload->data();
    $id = $this->get('id');
    $this->response($image, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that:

```
$image = $this->upload->data();
```

Is not the correct way of grabbing the posted file. What is the correct way?

Comment: Looks like you should add a proper port to your address. `localhost:8080...`

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('data')) {
        echo 'error';
    } else {

        return array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

and in your controller use this:

```
$this->data['data'] = $this->do_upload();
```

and make the form as form-data or if you use binary send a header of what the file is like jpeg or what and then echo the file

Comment: First I received the error "THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST" after making that directory I get an object returned. How to insert this file into my database from there?

Comment: you know it is better to save the image name in the database not the binary content. usually binary coded images are used for very high secure images. make the form multipart/form-data and get the image name. var_dump the $this->data['data'] to see what fields are in there and then get the file name and store in database. file is in you project and you have the name of the image ... you can use it to load in html page